# What is this UDP traffic to 230.0.0.1? And how can I block it?

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, udp, multicast

My VM is of IP 192.168.3.20 in the network of 192.168.3.0/24. While running iptraf command on my machine, I am getting the response as shown in the attached image.

I can't understand what kind of traffic is this (originated from 192.168.3.4). Also, I want to block it.

Can anyone help?

[image: iptraf_capture]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is almost for sure nothing to be concerned about. 230.0.0.1 is part of 224.0.0.0 - 239.255.255.255  Internet Assigned Numbers Authority and these IP addresses are not routed to the internet, so nothing to block.

Use a Packet Sniffer to see what the packets are.

I see a 224 address in Comm View and it is just my Television. You may have a similar device causing the packets.

[image]

Comment: Many thanks John. Can you please tell me what this n1-fwp service is?

Comment: It is most likely a local device on your network and it is using traffic on your network.  You would need to look at your devices, but the IP you posted is definitely just local.

Comment: Thanks, John. It was very helpful.

Answer (score -1):

On my network, UPD traffic to 230.0.0.1, port 6666 is from a computer with Unreal Engine.  This is a popular engine used to create games.

I think it's to find other instances of Unreal Engine on the network... I presume this is for local network multiplayer games.

So, for example, if Fortnite were running, you'd see this traffic.